# Ubuntu Launcher Folder not working

Tags: unity, python, software-center, launcher, 17.04

I downloaded and installed ubuntu-launcher-folder after reading a recommendation on OMG Ubuntu and it refuses to run.

I tried to start it up via the terminal and got this...

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/unity_launcher_folders/**init**.py:21:
>   PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use
>   gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the
>   right version gets loaded.   from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk,
>   GdkPixbuf, Pango, Gio Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/bin/unity-launcher-folders", line 46, in 
>       import unity_launcher_folders   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/unity_launcher_folders/**init**.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from generateIcon import GenerateIcon   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/unity_launcher_folders/generateIcon.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       import Image ImportError: No module named Image

can someone please help me?

Comment: Exactly where did you get the package from?

Comment: it was an OMG Ubuntu link

Comment: Well that's less than informative. If it was from here - https://launchpad.net/~asukhovatkin/+archive/ubuntu/unity-launcher-folders than it was made for 14.04 & likely would have issues with later Ubuntu releases. Take a look at this thread, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2325175 comment #5 shows expicitly how to fix for 16.04. Maybe that'll work in 17.04 or point you in right direction..

Comment: http://unity-folders.exceptionfound.com/

Comment: Edit:, see it worked, great.. (- the package you got was basically same as ppa, same author, ect.